# How do you unlock the Jumbo Rampager award in Kirby Mass Attack?

Tags: kirby-mass-attack

What stage do you need to go to to get the Jumbo Rampager award in Kirby Mass Attack? You need to defeat 10 enemies using the Jumbo Candy.

Answer (score 1):

1-9 is a good level for this - it has two Jumbo candies, which should be enough to get you to the end of the stage, and help you get this award.